# Recursion restarting loop (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion, for-loop

I have a question regarding C++. So I have made this program, that computes all possible combinations to solve a problem using recursion(instead of 9 loops). This is a part of the code:

```
int used[9];
nMin=1000;

void Combinations(int index)
    {
      if(index>8)
      {
        return;
      }
      for(int i=k;i<4;i++)
      {
        used[index]=i;
        if (sum<nMin && Check())//Checks the solution
        {
          nMin = sum;
          used[i]=0;
          return;
        }
        else
        {
          Combinations(index+1);
        }
      }
}
```

The for loop, that should repeat 4 times resets every time recursive call returns. In other words the loop variable is set to 0. Is that just how it works, and do I have to store current loop variable value, or is there another way.

Edit: thank you guys, for detailed information and your answers. The code worked after a few tweaks.

Comment: Was "I that just how it works" a question or a statement?

Comment: Is your complaint that `i` is being set to 0 after the call to `Combinations(index+1)`? If so, how are you testing this and are you sure you're not looking at another incarnation of `i`?

Answer (score 2):

`int i` is a local variable that exists within the context of that for loop for that instance of that function call. When you make a recursive call to the same function, you're pushing a brand new instance of that function call on the stack, which has its own for loop with its own `int i` variable. They are in no way connected to each other.

If you want all recursive calls to the function to share a counter, you will need to define it as a static variable, and define it outside of the scope of the for loop, like this:

```
void Combinations(int index)
{
     static int persistentCounter;
```

This will maintain it's value in recursive calls.

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading this correctly, your question is whether the loop variable `i` will be protected/preserved by the recursive calls to `Combinations`.

The answer is **yes, the value of the loop counter will be preserved**. The reason is [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). Each time the function is called, the stack creates space for a new variable `i` scoped to the current call. This means all interactions with `i` during a function call are with the `i` created for that specific call.

Note: The C/C++ language standards have no explicit notion of a stack. This is actually an implementation detail for the implementation of automatic storage.